# "NULL" value is added in array of localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I'm using this code to add values to local storage:

```
rowSettings[counter] = [value1, value2, value3];
localStorage.setItem("rowSettings", JSON.stringify(rowSettings));
```

The result in the localStorage is then:

```
[null,[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]].
```

So how come "null" is being added?

In Chome developer tool I get:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null".
```

This happens when retrieving the objects back:

```
var row =0;
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rowSettings'));
//Start each function
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   console.log(retrievedObject[row][i]);
}
row++;
//End each function
```

Comment: Add complete code of how you're creating and using `rowSettings`

Comment: You are pushng some value in array which is `null` at the time of push operation. Your code looks fine..I would prefer `rowSettings.push()` over `rowSettings[counter]`

Comment: What value is `counter` starting at? If it begins at `1`, the `0` index will be left `undefined` but still treated as part of the array (and converted to `null` by `JSON.stringify()`).

Comment: Does any value exist at zeroth index of rowSettings array before converting it to JSON string?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle and reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

When you built rowSettings, you started (counter) at index 1 instead of 0. So the 0th element is null.
Answer found based on Jonathan's comment.